# Using If within a Textjoin formula but ignoring blank cells

Tags: excel, array-formulas, textjoin

I have been trying to use a Text-join formula to pull together comments based on whether there is certain text in adjacent cells. I've used this formula which has worked fine:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" "&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),"TRUE",IF(CA2:CA100="Yes",BZ2:BZ100,""))
```

However, is there a way to stop the formula returning a "0" if the cell in column `BZ` is blank?

I've looked at other threads and tried the following but can't seem to get it right?

```
=TEXTJOIN(" "&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),"TRUE",IF(AND(CA2:CA100="Yes",BZ2:BZ100<>""),'Main Data'!BZ2:BZ100,""))
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Coming late to the party with a UDF solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050#50719050).

Answer (score 0):

Array formula do not like AND, use `*` instead:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" "&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),"TRUE",IF(('Main Data'!CA2:CA100="Yes") * ('Main Data'!BZ2:BZ100<>""),'Main Data'!BZ2:BZ100,""))
```

And remember to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter